# Quickly compute inverse summation

Tags: performance-tuning, summation

I'd like to look at behavior of $f(n)$ for the following $f$

$$\begin{array}{lll}
g(s,n)&=&\frac{1}{n}\sum_i^n \left(1-\frac{1}{i}\right)^s\\
f(n)&=&\text{smallest } s \text{ such that } g(s,n)<10^{-6}
\end{array}$$

My naive implementation is below, but it's too slow to make a good plot in reasonable time. Any tips how to speed this up?

```
g[s_, n_] := Total@Table[(1. - 1/i)^s, {i, 1, n}]/n;
f[n_] := (For[i = 1, i < 20 n, i++,
   If[g[i, n] < 10^(-6), Break[]]]; i)
f[1000] // Timing (* {1.74248, 11243} *)
```

Comment: the hypothesis is that $f(n)$ is linear in $n$

Comment: Maybe something along the lines of `FindRoot[g[s, 1000] == 10^-6, {s, 100}]`?

Comment: Was just in the process of trying Carl Woll's suggestion:

Comment: zero[n_, s_] := n 10^(-6) - NSum[(1 - 1/i)^s, {i, 1, n}]

Comment: lastSolution = s /. FindRoot[zero[10, s], {s, 2}];Table[{2^n, 
  lastSolution = s /. FindRoot[zero[2^n, s], {s, lastSolution}]}, {n, 
  1, 12}];ListPlot[%]  but slows down for larger n...

Comment: Uses previous solution as the initial guess for the root.

Comment: If $f(n)$ is linear in $n$, then using an initial values based on the linear regression $f(n)$ on $n$ for say values of $n$ from 2 to 100:  `data = Table[{n, f[n]}, {n, 2, 100}];
lm = LinearModelFit[data, n, n]; nn = 1000; FindRoot[g[s, nn] == 10^-6, {s, lm[nn]}]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could do it recursively, using `FindRoot` with starting point determined by previous value (per comment by @CraigCarter).

```
ff[3] = 1;
ff[n_Integer] := 
 ff[n] = Floor[
   s /. FindRoot[
     Sum[((i - 1)/i)^s, {i, 2, n}] == n*10^(-6), {s, ff[n - 1]},
WorkingPrecision -> Log[2, n] + $MachinePrecision]]
```

Check result:

```
ListPlot[Table[ff[n], {n, 3, 100}]]
```

[image]

Comment: thanks! Fixed a typo, now the result seems perfectly linear. There's probably an analytic way to derive this

Comment: Thanks @YaroslavBulatov. Does look like it is approximately linear.